# Is it possible to do research in both Computer Architecture and Security

Tags: hardware, research, career, academia

I just finished with my MSc in Computer Science and Engineering (Security study-line) with a thesis on cache timing attacks on virtualized environments. I also have an MEng in Electronic and Electrical Engineering. I am interested in both Computer Architecture and Security from a hardware perspective.

I am now considering taking an academic path, probably starting with some research assistance and then doing a PhD. Is there a point where these research fields meet? What topics represent a good mesh between the two fields?

Are there companies that are combining these fields?

Comment: Is perhaps the existence and usage of TPM modules in the ballpark of what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

I think the most interesting work, academically, is at Cambridge (check https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/capsicum/documentation.html)

ARM is doing research into this, as is Intel and Apple, but there are fewer citations to start digging into.

Comment: I'd say https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/ctsrd/cheri/ sounds like an even better fit.